# Remove repeating values from 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a 2d array like this.

```
int[,] arr = new int[3,5]{
             {1,2,3,4,5},
             {10,22,53,4,35},
             {1,12,13,45,51}};
```

Now i want to remove all the repeating values keeping order intact(i.e. after deleting the value index of other elements should not change)

Expected output is :

```
1  2  3  4  5
10 22 53 0  0
0  12 13 45 51
```

Note: repeating values can be replaced with 0.

This is my attempt. can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                int a = matrix[i, j];
                int flag = 1;
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++)
                    {
                        if (a == matrix[k, l] && flag == 0)
                        {
                            matrix[k, l] = 0;
                        }
                        else if (a == matrix[k, l] && flag != 0)
                        {
                            flag--;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

P.S. Is there any other way to do this, without iterating 4 for loops ?

Comment: What output *are* you getting?

Comment: some values are not removed

Comment: @Mr.Bhanushali you have matrix 3x5 but initialize it with 5x5 correct quetion please

Comment: yeah sorry.. @S.Petrosov

Comment: Why did 35 get removed in your example?  It was the only one.

Comment: I sugguest using a `HashSet` to keep track of the numbers you've already seen

Comment: @Mr.Bhanushali Apparently, there is not any problem with your code! As I've run, it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using a `HashSet` to keep track of the numbers you've already seen

```
var seen = new HasSet<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        if(!seen.Add(matrix[i,j]))
        {
            matrix[i,j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This works because `HashSet<T>.Add` returns `false` if the value is already in the hash set.

Also notice the use of `GetLength` instead of hard coding the length.  This will make the code more reusable since you don't need to change it to make it work with an array of a different size.

Comment: Please, `matrix.GetLength(0);` instead of magic number `3` and `matrix.GetLength(1)` instead of `5`.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I agree, but I was just trying to show how the existing code can be updated to use a `HashSet`.  Magic numbers seem like a separate issue, but I'll "fix" it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is example how you can implement this in more developer friendly mode:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] arr = new int[3, 5]{
     {1,2,3,4,5},
     {10,22,53,4,35},
     {1,12,13,45,51}};

    int[,] newArray = new int[arr.GetLength(0), arr.GetLength(1)];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (!ArrayHasValue(newArray, arr[i, j]))
            {
                newArray[i, j] = arr[i, j];
            }
            else
            {
                newArray[i, j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < newArray.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(newArray[i, j]+" ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

public static bool ArrayHasValue<T>(T [,] arr, T value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (arr[i,j].Equals(value))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Off course the implemention of ArrayHasValue is not the best one and needs more validation in case if you use not int arrays.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt:

```
int[,] arr = new int[3, 5]{
             {1,2,3,4,5},
             {10,22,53,4,35},
             {1,12,13,45,51}};

var rowsize = arr.GetLength(1);
var colsize = arr.GetLength(0);
var size = rowsize * colsize;

// index = row*rowlength + col
for (int idx1 = 0; idx1 < size; idx1++)
{
    var col = idx1 % rowsize;
    var row = idx1 / rowsize;
    var value = arr[row, col];
    if (value == 0) continue; // ignore 0's

    for (int idx2 = idx1 + 1; idx2 < size; idx2++)
    {
        var col2 = idx2 % rowsize;
        var row2 = idx2 / rowsize;
        if (arr[row2, col2] == value)
        {
            arr[row2, col2] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

- Treat the two-dimensional array as a single-dimensional one. That saves two loops
- Walk through the entire array, noting the value there
- Walk through *the rest* of the array (skipping the part you already had), checking for the noted value and setting to 0 is found
- Use GetLength to avoid hardcoding the size of the array.

Comment: You could just use a `foreach` for the inner loop.  Also `arr.Length` will be the total number of item in all dimensions of the array.

Comment: @juharr - you do not want to erase the original value

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not very efficient. You can try to solve this problem using `HashSet`. The idea is to go through the matrix, for every cell you have two conditions :

1. Value is present in Set, in this case set `matrix[i, j]` to `0`
2. Valus is not present in Set, in this case add it to the Set

Comment: Actually you just add it and the result will tell you if it was already in the set or not.